# Hosting the MakeCode for EV3 Mindstorms editor locally

Tags: lego-mindstorms, makecode

According to the [documentation](https://makecode.microbit.org/offline), the Microbit flavor of MakeCode can be hosted locally by downloading the entire PXT Toolchain. I'm wondering whether the procedure described at https://github.com/Microsoft/pxt-microbit will work for other MakeCode targets, in particular for the EV3 Mindstorms.

Answer (score 0):

This generally only works for open source targets. EV3 is not, as of now, open source.